# net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED Android error while opening WebPage in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-webview

Android WebPage showing net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED while opening Android activity
Embedded with with WebPage Tag

I tried to provide permission in Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

webview:

```
    WebView webView;
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webbrowser);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.loadUrl("http://basic-testing-faq.blogspot.com/");
```

I getting `net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED`

[image]

Answer (score 21):

Uninstall.

Install again.

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure internet permission is given and add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` if you use http website.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="in.example.application">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="m">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was the permission issue!

Answer (score 1):

All you need, clear the data, un-install the app an re-installed it. After that, put this code to 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and put this code to webview class

```
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
    wvMakFukinWalker = findViewById(R.id.wv_mak); 
    // wvMakFukinWalker is my WebView
    // wv_mak the id

    WebSettings webSettings = wvMakFukinWalker.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    wvMakFukinWalker.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wvMakFukinWalker.loadUrl("http://yourdomain.com/");
```

// webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); ==>> I think: this is your solution

Answer (score 0):

> The following finally worked for me

```
package com.example.webview01;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView web;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webv);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        web.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");

        WebSettings websettings = web.getSettings();

        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        websettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        websettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        websettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if (web.canGoBack()){
        web.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

> The following lines must be included

```
    WebSettings websettings = web.getSettings();

    websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```