# webview in Android Studio with error ""webpage could not be loaded because net:: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED""

Tags: java, android, webview

In my previous project I've implemented a review that works fine.. but when I created a new webview and implement these features then they works like this.

The error is stated that "webpage could not be loaded  because of net:: ERR_ACCESS_DENIED"

my main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads (false);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.dailytennistips.com");
        Log.e("Link","http://www.dailytennistips.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }
```

xml file

```
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="221dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="243dp" />
```

Comment: here is my error: https://imgur.com/a/zDlspAd

Comment: Try some answers from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312065/neterr-access-denied-android-error-while-opening-webpage-in-android-activity)..

Comment: Have you added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in your manifest?

Comment: @ADM thanks dear... the main issue is i don't know.. but i uninstaled the app and then install again... that worked for me ... bundle of thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's because your domain doesn't use SSL. Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your manifest application tag like so:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```