# Critical errors regarding firebase class in android studio

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, firebase

I need my app to load a local file, but I've been getting the same result every time I run it, regardless of the permissions I've added to manifest:

[image]

My code (manifest, main activity, security):

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.recall"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    tools:ignore="GradleOverrides">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText"
        tools:targetApi="n"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".Firebase"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="TODO">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
            tools:replace="android:value" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.recall;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///assets/menu.html");

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Firebase

```
package com.example.recall;

import android.app.Service;

public abstract class Firebase extends Service {
}
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_site_domain.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

These are the recurring errors I get when I run the app:

```
2020-07-16 21:07:37.363 239-245/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2020-07-16 21:07:37.371 239-245/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2020-07-16 21:07:38.320 387-387/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2020-07-16 21:07:38.321 387-387/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2020-07-16 21:07:39.256 389-389/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2020-07-16 21:07:39.256 389-389/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
**2020-07-16 21:08:30.176 2343-2343/? E/FirebaseInstanceId: binding to the service failed**
```

Numerous sources state that the problem is generally resolved with adding the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but that hasn't worked for me.

Question: What should I add to the Firebase class?

Important notes:
I am using Android Studio on a Mac Sierra OS X, and the only emulator I've used is a Pixel 2 API 30.

Comment: Did you uninstall and install the application again?
After adding the permissions.
Usually solves the problem.

Also, good read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56312065/neterr-access-denied-android-error-while-opening-webpage-in-android-activity